# how to host a version control on my own website

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I have a website hosted with godaddy. Basically for my work I use TFS. For my personal visual studio 2010 projects I use sourcesafe for version control but obviously I need to have it's data store on the local machine.

I need something that I can use my sql server database on my website to store the version control data. I'm not familiar with git, subversion and all those good stuffs, but I'm working on understanding them. Right now I couldn't decide on any specific ones. Every time I search for opensource version control there is a whole lot of options I just couldn't see which is what I need.

My basic requirement is I should be able to check-in check-out my visual studio files and keep them in my website, and access it from anywhere just like TFS. I need it in my website so I don't have any data size restrictions.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: I would never keep these things in the same place. If you lose your site, for whatever reason, you also lose all ability to rebuild it.

Comment: FogCreek offers FogBugz and Kiln completely free for up to two users - Kiln is a Mercurial server which has many great features. They do not have data size restrictions. Also this would take away the single point of failure in the case that something happens to your website (hacked, hardware failure etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you question, You can use [TFS Service Preview](http://tfspreview.com/), you can also use [TFS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#tfs-express) on your machine and expose it to the internet.

Comment: TFS Service Preview looks interesting, but there is no other information in that website. I couldn't figure out if it is free forever or something that I can rely on.

Comment: unfortunately there is not, because as Microsoft said, they are focus now on functionality more than pricing, but from my point of view, I expect to be available for free for small teams (5 users or less)